# Android studio always create a new package whenever I create a new Java class or AIDL file

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an new Android project in Android Studio.

I have created an package under `src/main/java/` its name is `com.my.droid.shaker` .

But when I right click on the package & create a new Java class, Android studio always create a new package with name `droid.my.com.shaker` & put my new Java class under this new package. Same thing also happens for my AIDL file.

Why Android Studio do that? Why I can't create java class under my package `com.my.droid.shaker`. It is really annoying. Please help me to get rid of it.

Comment: When you create a new project, a "Company domain" is asked. There if you put "com.my.droid", your main package will be "droid.my.com".

Comment: Why Android Studio doing this? Is it a convention nowadays? Sounds stupid to reverse the way I want. Shouldn't company domain always start with "com.XXX.YYY" and use it as package? I don't understand why Android Studio doing this.

Comment: Package names **are** reversed domain names. It is not about Android Studio it is just the way it is. Domain name : "www.google.com"; Package name : "com.google.www". All you have to do is to write your "Company domain" like a normal website url.

Comment: How can I change my "Company domain" in Android Studio for my already created project then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reverse you whole project package you need to open your AndroidManifest.
There you should have *package="droid.my.com"*
Right click on "droid" -> refactor -> rename -> rename package
Rename it "com"
Then right click on "com" (the last one), and do the same to rename it "droid"

Answer (score 0):

this can be fixed in option compact middle packages(rigth click on the project bar)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).